# iOS Camera not opening

Tags: ios, camera

I created an app a couple of years ago and had it working no problem at all. I've been asked to resurrect it and have stumbled apron a problem. When selecting a button to open up the camera and/or photo library it comes up with this message when choosing either option:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x100a13400>  on :<ViewController: 0x100843a00> which is already presenting <UIAlertController:0x1001e8d40>`
```

Im wondering has there been changes between iOS's that i need to amend my code because of? Here is what I currently have:

```
- (IBAction)pickImage {

    AVAuthorizationStatus status = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) { // authorized

    }
    else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusDenied){ // denied

    }
    else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted){ // restricted


    }
    else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined){ // not determined

        [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
            if(granted){ // Access has been granted ..do something

            } else { // Access denied ..do something

            }
        }];
    }
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pick Image"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"from Camera", @"from Library", nil] ;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
            [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
            [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                message:@"Your device has no camera."
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [imageView setImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Many Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not able to replicate that error message with that code, however, you can try replacing your UIActionSheet and UIAlertView with a UIAlertController.

Both of these are deprecated as of iOS 8.0, and have been replaced with the UIAlertController.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/

You can set the preferred style attribute to "UIAlertControllerStyleAlert" or "UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet".